# how to Create subscription for sent items folder using Microsoft graph api

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

following post request give an error when creating a subscription for the Sent Items folder using Microsoft Graph

```
var apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions";
```

**Request**

```
{
  "resource": "me/mailFolders('Sent Items')/messages",
  "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
  "clientState": "320a6f10-9c62-4e59-a395-8cd27941b597",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.site/aaaa-6f49-4906-aaaa-e911f9391695",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-08-28T12:53:41.4830081+00:00"
}
```

**Error Response**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: Bad Request]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "359f51a6-5b12-41f6-8a02-a68ba4c10585",
      "date": "2018-08-27T06:42:18"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed the resource property value for folder name 'Sent Items' to '**SentItems**' . here is the working request

```
{
  "resource": "me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages",
  "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
  "clientState": "320a6f10-9c62-4e59-a395-8cd27941b597",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.site/aaaa-6f49-4906-aaaa-e911f9391695",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-08-29T12:53:41.4830081+00:00"
}
```

Comment: Nice catch.  For future reference (for both of us) the list of well-known folder names are here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailfolder

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the webhook.site test site that you are using does not implement the [validation token protocol](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation) that is required to setup a subscription.  The webhook must return the value of the validationToken query parameter in the response body for the subscription to be created correctly.

Comment: in there i didn't add my real webhook url .i validated webhook url and it is working for   {resource": "me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages}. i think this "ExtensionError" is different issue